# How to display multiple audio files in google colab?

Tags: audio, google-colaboratory, display

I would like to display multiple audio files in google colab, but I found that only one is possible in one codeblock. Therefore I was thinking, whether I could generate code blocks with a given text.

Something like:

```
for i in range(0,4):
  create_code_block("display.Audio(str(sound_paths[" + str(i) + "]))")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistake `display.Audio` for displaying. It's just creating Audio objects.

You need this instead.

```py
display.display(display.Audio(filename))
```

And try to avoid overwrite the `display`. Don't do this

```py
from IPython import display  # don't do
```

Because you cannot use the old `display` anymore.

Normally you can just

```
display(Audio(...))
```

Now you would need to use

```
display.display(display.Audio(...))
```